# cleos system deposit rex assertion error

Tags: cleos

When I use the command

`cleos --print-request -v -u https://api1.eosasia.one/ system rex deposit -x 60 myaccounthere '3.0 EOS'`

I got the following errors:

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: must deposit core token
pending console output: 
Stack Trace:
wasm_interface.cpp:924 eosio_assert
apply_context.cpp:72 exec_one
```

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: hm maybe try 4 0's of precision: 3.0000 EOS.

Comment: yeah, it works. thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Nat's comment is right, after specifying the amount '3.0000 EOS', the command execute successfully.

```
cleos --print-request -v -u https://api1.eosasia.one/ system rex deposit -x 60 myaccounthere '3.0000 EOS'
```